# How to trigger an onclick function in js only if input field is not empty?

Tags: javascript, html, function

Here, I want the function to trigger only if i have typed something in the input field. If it's empty I want to alert that it can't be empty. I tried if else condition but it doesn't help. I even tried using typeof but no matter what the type is string.

```js
const input  =  document.querySelector("#input");


function myFunc(){
let name = input.value;
if(name==null){
alert("PLEASE ENTER YOUR NAME")
} else{
alert('Hello'+' '+name);
}
};
```

```html
<body>
 
  
  <input placeholder="Enter your name" id="input">
  <button id="btn" onclick="myFunc()">Click me!</button>
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

`input.value` is not null when the input is empty, its just empty string.
try this:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#input");

function myFunc() {
  let name = input.value;
  if (name == "") {
    alert("PLEASE ENTER YOUR NAME")
  } else {
    alert('Hello' + ' ' + name);
  }
};
```

```html
<body>
  <input placeholder="Enter your name" id="input">
  <button id="btn" onclick="myFunc()">Click me!</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for empty string as well. In practice, you are never going to get a null value for input.value but it's not bad to program conservatively

```
function myFunc(){
let name = input.value;
if(name==null || name.length == 0){
alert("PLEASE ENTER YOUR NAME")
} else{
alert('Hello'+' '+name);
}
};
```

or you can take advantage of how awesomely Javascript implements the not (!) operator and just do:

```
function myFunc(){
let name = input.value;
if(!name){
alert("PLEASE ENTER YOUR NAME")
} else{
alert('Hello'+' '+name);
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to test for empty/space and it is not recommended to have inline event handlers

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const input = document.getElementById("input");
  const name = input.value.trim();
  alert(name ? 'Hello ' + name : 'Please enter your name')
});
```

```html
<input placeholder="Enter your name" id="input">
<button type="button" id="btn">Click me!</button>
```